# Define node host and port from file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im using node with express and when I create server im listening to port 3000 
in app.js by code,my question if there is any way to define it (host &port ) from exteranl file like some config json or something.if I want to be able to provide it from file .

Comment: Sure.  Read in a configuration file and pass those values to express.  Is there something in particular you have tried and doesn't work?

Comment: you can also pass them using process.argv, which lets you change them each time it's run

Comment: @dandavis-can you please give an example for it,I not really understand what does it mean and if  this solution is better then the others below,thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create config file, config.json:

```
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3000
}
```

Use `require()` to read it:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require("./config.json");
app.listen(config.port, config.host, ...
```

Comment: Thanks voted up!last question...your solution is best practice for production use or some workaround?I ask it since I fairly new to node...,Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is a good technique.  Another good option would be to read environment variables.  Eg `app.listen(process.env.PORT, ...`.  That gives you some flexibility in that environment variables can be set any number of ways.  Use whichever works best for your situation, or even a combination.

Answer (score 4):

You can "require" a config.

your config.json (can be js too).

```
{
  "environment": "development",
  "other": "value"
}
```

in app.js:

```
var cfg = require('./config.json');
```

Now you can access `cfg` properties.

Comment: Thanks voted up!last question...your solution is best practice for production use or some workaround?I ask it since I fairly new to node...,Thanks in advance!